# Enabling data Core in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, xcode5.1

I have already the Xcode project in xcode 5.1.1, and i am unable to add .xcdatamodel file
as descriped in the below link.

http://wiresareobsolete.com/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/

Ie:

```
 From Xcode, control-click on the Resources fold inside the Groups & Files pane
```

Where the Resource Folder available?. I do not see any folder in the project navigator?

did i miss anything to look into ?

Comment: Be very careful following a tutorial from 5 years ago. A lot has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*http://wiresareobsolete.com/2009/12/adding-core-data-existing-iphone-projects/* is good enough to add core data model.
you have to add new file -> core data-> data model.
this will give you core data model.
There is no need  of resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Resource` folder is not there you can create it. `File->New->Group` (or right click on the project navigator -> New Group). Its is a folder for grouping your files(All the resources like images,sounds will usually put it in `Resource` folder) nothing more than that. Some Xcode's will create it for you while creating the project, otherwise you could create it.

It doesn't matter `.xcdatamodel` file is in resource folder or not. But it makes sense if you have grouping like `Source`, `Resources` or logical grouping also